# Why don't I have access to a variable created in the upper scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Im struggling with this js code for some reason. I can't access variables inside the ajax function.
I tried solving this by placing the "formatted" variable above the ajax function but I can't access it from inside. How do I solve this?

```
angular.module('ireg')
.controller("compoundSearchController", function(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.searchText = "Enter your search here...";
    vm.compounds = getJSON();

    function getJSON(){
        var formatted = "initial";  

        console.log(formatted); // equals initial

        $.ajax({url: "http://localhost:8080/ireg/app/php/returnAllCompounds.php", success: function(result){
            formatted = jQuery.parseJSON( result );
            console.log(formatted); //equals the correct object
        }})

        console.log(formatted); // equals initial
        return formatted;
    }

    console.log(vm.compounds); // equals initial

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous behavior of AJAX calls is the reason of difference between actual behavior and expected behavior.

Update your code to

```
var formatted = "initial";  

$.ajax({url: "http://localhost:8080/ireg/app/php/returnAllCompounds.php", success: function(result){
    formatted = jQuery.parseJSON( result );
    vm.compounds = formatted;
}})
```

Comment: ( http://imgur.com/wLUbeqt ) As you can see outside of the ajax function the variable is still initial? Is something outside of the provided code you believe? I only reference it here.

Comment: Again we are trying to access "formatted" prior to response received of AJAX. If you move the console.log inside the ajax callback function, you will be able to see the updated value i.e. from line no. 14 to line no. 12 as per your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You could not get response of ajax call outside it `success` because they are `asynchronous` in nature. You need to use their call back to get that like `success` or you could also use `.then` function which get call when ajax call gets resolved.

**NOTE**

> Don't mix jQuery ajax with AngularJS that will mess up with `digest`
>   cycle, you need to force it manually, Do replace ajax with `$http`

**Update**

Below is angular version `$.ajax`

```
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/ireg/app/php/returnAllCompounds.php")
    .success(function(result){
        formatted = jQuery.parseJSON( result );
        console.log(formatted); //equals the correct object
    }});
```

Comment: @Chris Chevalier does it helped you?